# Failed to fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried fetch a list of books from the server using an Axios request in your React component.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const books = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Harry Potter and the Sorcerer\'s Stone', author: 'J.K. Rowling' },
  { id: 2, title: 'The Hobbit', author: 'J.R.R. Tolkien' },
  { id: 3, title: 'To Kill a Mockingbird', author: 'Harper Lee' }
];

app.get('/api/books', (req, res) => {
  res.json(books);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const BookList = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/books')
      .then(response => {
        setBooks(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching books:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Book List</h2>
      <ul>
        {books.map(book => (
          <li key={book.id}>{book.title} by {book.author}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookList;
```

Despite the server being operational and reachable at the specified endpoint, you encountered a network error and were unable to retrieve the list of books.

Comment: no this is not a homework, I did this for practice.

I got a CORS error, but after using the CORS middleware and setting the CORS headers to allow requests from a specific origin (in my case, http://localhost:3001) with the
 line app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3001' }));  
it worked. Do I always need to release the port first when using the CORS middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue. It's a security feature implemented by web browsers to restrict webpages from making requests to a different domain than the one that served the original webpage. The error specifically states that there is no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header present on the requested resource.

To resolve this issues just install cors in your express server and update the code as following it should work fine:

```
npm i cors
```

.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')

const books = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Harry Potter and the Sorcerer\'s Stone', author: 'J.K. Rowling' },
  { id: 2, title: 'The Hobbit', author: 'J.R.R. Tolkien' },
  { id: 3, title: 'To Kill a Mockingbird', author: 'Harper Lee' }
];

app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/books', (req, res) => {
  res.json(books).status(200);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```